# Create a custom template for a custom URL

Tags: theming, webforms

I'm using the Webform module and need to redirect users to a custom URL (with replacement tokens) once they have completed a job application in order to track conversions in Google Analytics.

I've set the URL to `/application-completed/[job-ref-number]`. This redirect works but I really want a custom template to be rendered rather than the default Webform confirmation message on a 404 page.

I've tried the following in my template.php file but the issue here is that it's a completely blank template (not rendering html.tpl.php), whereas I'd prefer to render the page.tpl.php template and simply replace the `$page['content']` area with the custom template (would this be a node template?)

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  if (drupal_match_path(drupal_get_path_alias(), 'application-completedy/*')) {
    $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__mycustomtemplate';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track. You just need to also create a file named page__mycustomtemplate.tpl.php (place it in your mytheme/templates directory). The starting point for this file should either be the page.tpl.php in your mytheme/templates dir (if there is one), or the one in mysiteroot/modules/system. Simply open one of these and save it as page__mycustomtemplate.tpl.php in your theme's templates dir. Then you can replace `<?php print render($page['content']); ?>` with your custom text/markup.